# Does an active web-sockets connection use CPU time in Azure?

Tags: .net, azure, websocket, signalr

With the free plan on Azure App-service, you are provided with 60 minutes of CPU time per day. I have a web app that uses SignalR for real-time communication. My question is, does 1 minute of active connection translate to 1 minute of CPU time? If that is the case I would need 60*24 minutes of CPU time per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are self-hosting SignalR, the protocol includes a ping at regular intervals (I think the default is 15 seconds). The server uses CPU to respond to that ping.

You can see the request and response for keep-alive by:

1. Going to Chrome Developer Tools network tab.
2. Filter by just WS.
3. Inspect the Messages tab on the SignalR hub connection.

You'll see requests and response for {"type":6}.

Comment: Ok, so the CPU time should be much lower than real time. I will run a test tomorrow and see on average what the ratio will be and update this comment.